# how to get only the local file path but no file using a 'fake' upload form in yii2

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, upload, yii2

I'm looking for a way to use an upload form but without uploading anything, just use it to write the local path name on the database.

This would be very useful in my project, 'cause this way the employees won't manually copy and paste the local path in the inputText form.. drastically reducing the risk of mistaping.

Thanks a lot to everybody,
lordcroci

Comment: You cannot access the local path of a file for security reasons.

Comment: There's no wat to do that? absolutely no trick even with javascript + php ?

Thanks

Comment: No. It's a security feature of modern browsers.

Comment: I resolved.. in internet explorer it is actually possible.

Comment: Internet explorer only, yes. But that's only because of it's shockingly bad security level. This will not work in any other modern browser.

Comment: yep for sure, but working on the inside of the factory we do not need so much security as for outside applications